# SQL CE 4 and Sql Ide's

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

What tools does everyone use to work with the SQl CE 4? With 3.5 we could open it in SQL Server Studio Management Studio but this is no longer an option it seems... and doing it in VS only allows you to execute one command at a time.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1/

Comment: I have that already, it doesn't let you execute in batch. I tried using both a GO statement and ;

Comment: Basically I just want to be able to run multiple insert statements, and it doesn't seem to even let me do that...

Comment: This is a bug that has been fixed in the latest release 2.0.0.3 - let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: If you have VS Premium or higher, you can use the builtin query tool part of the Data menu.

Comment: @ErikEJ - I have the latest 2.2.0.3. I just realized though that it works with GO statements. The "GO" is case sensitive though. If it's not capitalized it will through a query parsing error.

Comment: @ErikEJ - thanks for pointing out the built in query tool! I can run multiple statements there, and it's more like sql server studio manager, which is great. Now on to the next task to get it working with EF4 in WinForms =)

Answer (score 2):

This is another example of inconsistency among MS tools - a new version of SQL Server CE is here few months but rest of the MS tools will not support it till next release. Especially with management studio this is huge failure.

As I know MS provides only one tool to work with SQL Server CE 4: [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/features.aspx)

For Visual Studio you can use mentioned [SQL Server Compact Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1/) and you can check its author [blog for list of other tools](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2009/04/sql-compact-3rd-party-tools.html).

Comment: Yes, it's really annoying. I think I'm just going to revert to using SQL CE 3.5. The one new feature I really wanted was that I think it now supports auto incremented key with Entity Framework. I'll stick with generating my own keys for now, or using GUID (which I really don't want).